# How to prevent entering text on a NumericUpdown at textchange event when certain condtion met?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to prevent users from typing on a NumericUpdown when a certain condition was met. In my example when user reach 3 decimal places i have to prevent user entering the 4 th decimal place. Currently I have this code in textchange event of the NumericUpdown. This is a WINFORM app. using c#

```
if(decimalPlaces>3)
{
ntxt.Parent.Focus();
}
```

This is working. Probelem with this code is when user try to enter the 4th number focus goes to another control. Nothing will happen. If user press the key again other numbers will be type on a textbox of that control. I dont want that. I just want to prevent entering further value to current NumericUpdown and focus should have in the last curser position too

Answer (score 0):

An idea to try, not sure if it will work in the context of your code.
In the event that the if statement is true, don't move focus away, round the value to 3DP.
Something like this:

```
    if(decimalPlaces>3)
    {
    Double Rnd = NumericUpdown.Value; 
    NumericUpdown.Value = Math.Round(Rnd, 3);
    }
```

Worth a try...